# I need a generic ajax request handler for asp.net

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an application that some pages use asp.net ajax calls and some others are using prototype ajax calls.

I want to know if theres a way using javascript to intercept all ajax requests no matter how they were created so I can execute a client custom script after every partial postback.

I want to have that code in a .js file included in all my pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting an event which you created yourself is a bit strange (and no, I don't think there is actually a way of doing it in this case). You just have to make a call from the right place in your code.